# python data extraction with non numeric charaters

Tags: python-2.7

I have a ascii file with different coordinates and time, I was able to extract coordinates but not time as time was in the format of
1980-01-01T20:55:49.257.

It would be very helpful if somebody could suggest how to remove (- T : ) characters and write the data into a new file  or suggest a method if there is any to read such kind of data.

I would like to have data like this

1980 01 01 20 55 49 257

thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date-in-python)

Comment: Short answer: use the third-party [iso8601](https://bitbucket.org/micktwomey/pyiso8601) module.

Comment: I sorted it out, thanks a lot